# cutting 20 feet asphalt driveway

Tags: cutting, asphalt

I should cut a stright line on my 20-feet asphalt driveway, and am wondering what would be a easy way of doing it. I was told that a worm drive circular saw could do that with a diamond blade. I don't have a worm drive circular saw but has a normal circular saw from Makita (7 1/2"). Would a normal circular saw be able to cut the asphalt? It is not that thick -- about 1 1/2 ". Or, would just renting a walk-behind concrete saw from HomeDepot be easier? When I check the fee, it is about $50 for 4 hour and $70 for a full day.

If a circular saw can get the job done easily, I don't want to spend over $50 but am concerned with that my circular saw might be damaged.

Thanks,

Comment: Buying a decent diamond blade will likely cost as much as or more than the rental. Do you have other uses for the blade that would justify the purchase?

Comment: The author of this website (http://reubenscube.net/2012/08/garage-how-to-cut-asphalt-with-a-circular-saw/) says that it costed $16 to buy a diamond blade. So, I thought it would be much cheaper than the rental fee...

Comment: Don't use your circular saw. Rent a concrete saw, or other tool designed for the task.

Comment: Whatever you use will be full of tar for the rest of its life. I wouldn't sacrifice my worm drive for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to do this with a circular saw, your "straight line" will look straight only to Salvatore Dali. A heavy duty street cutter is required.

Of course, what objective there could be in cutting a driveway we can only guess at.

Comment: Fiddy cents says he's installing an invisible dog fence, and will drop the wire in that slot.

Comment: In my case, my driveway slopes down to the steps for my deck. It's graded poorly and I want to replace that section with a small patio.